# Using a data frame value as a list name

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a list which contains fourteen data frames. Each data frame contains a final column which contains a value for the city. So it would like

```
[[1]]
   Row.Labels       brz   zone
1     3/31/09        NA   SNE
2     4/30/09        NA   SNE
3     5/31/09        NA   SNE

[[2]]
   Row.Labels       brz   zone
1     3/31/09        NA   FED
2     4/30/09        NA   FED
3     5/31/09        NA   FED

...
```

What I want to do is name each data frame within the list with the value from the zone column. I figured a quick for loop would do the trick but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

```
dataset <- do.call("list", lapply(file_list, FUN = function(files){ 
      read.csv(files, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}))

# doesn't work
for( j in 1:length(dataset) ) {
  names(dataset[j]) <- unique(dataset[[j]][,"zone"])
}
```

So the desired result of to name the first list element as SNE, the second list element as FED, and so forth. But I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Try `names(mylist) <- sapply(mylist, function(x) x$zone[1])`. In case it works, feel free to post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Or `names(mylist) <- unique(do.call(rbind, mylist)$"zone")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, unless 2 or more list elements have the same city name, right?

Comment: Have your tried this in your for-loop: `names(dataset)[j] <- unique(dataset)[[j]][,"zone"])` ... i.e. assigning to  j-th name rather than naming the j-th item. Probably safer to pick first "zone".

Comment: Minor correction to @BondedDust's suggestion - there's an errant closing parenthesis here: `dataset)[[j]]`.